# Adding a 120v branch to a 4 wire 240v?

Tags: electrical

[image]First post and question:

I have a spa serviced by a 240v 4 wire subpanel with GFI breaker. I would like to add a 120v branch with a GFI outlet for light duty (*light, music etc.*)

**Can I pull the power from one leg?**
*I realize that I will have to ground the new line and use the one leg of 240v and white neutral.*

Since it would have the existing GFI 240v beaker, **how would I setup the new 120v GFI breaker?**

*The spa is 40' away from main panel, I would like to avoid burying another line and conduit.*

Any ideas or concerns?

Comment: Super easy, just stick the GFCI breaker in one of the empty spaces in the subpanel, follow its instructions (you have to anyway: NEC 110.3B) and you're all set.  *Or are you out of spaces in that panel?  If so, pop the panel cover off and shoot us a pic of what's inside, then [edit] it into your question.*  If you haven't registered your account, please do so; it allows you to sign on from other devices (e.g. the phone you'd take a picture with).  Registering means setting up an email/password or using SSO with Google or Facebook. https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/login I think...

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the spa disconnect box please? (Include any labeling you find on it)

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Yes, my GFI breaker for spa is more than 15amps over spa motor. I will take photo of panel.

Comment: @DIYdude -- how many amps does the spa require (nameplate amps, not breaker rating), what size is the breaker in the upstream panel, and what size are the wires from a) the upstream panel to this spa box and b) the spa box to the spa?

Answer (score 1):

Most 240v spas have a 4 wire feed, so it is physically possible. The process for doing it would depend on the configuration of the spa disconnect, a picture of the disconnect would be good.

To legally do it where I live the breaker and wire in your panel that feeds the hot tub disconnect would need have capacity of 15A greater than the ampacity shown on the spa label.